# How to make same format in User column in r?

Tags: r

I have some problems referencing my data frame because the naming format is not same. I have dataframe something like:

```
myData <-  User                        freq
            17567123@hvr.ac.uk         9
            17567123                   1
            17567123@students.ac.uk    2
            hvr.ac.uk\17567123         1
            17567124@students.ac.uk    2
            17567124                   3
            Jhon                       1
```

To something like this:

```
> myData

   User        freq
1  17567123     13 
2  17567124     5   
3  Jhon         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove all characters after `"@"` or before the last `"\"` or `"/"`. Then, summarise the `freq` by `User`. Try this

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


myData <- read.table(header = T, text = "
User                       freq
17567123@hvr.ac.uk         9
17567123                   1
17567123@students.ac.uk    2
hvr/ac/uk/17567123         1
hvr.ac.uk\\17567123        1
17567124@students.ac.uk    2
17567124                   3
Jhon                       1
")

myData %>% group_by(User = str_remove(User, "(@.+$)|(^.+\\\\)|(^.+\\/)")) %>% summarise(freq = sum(freq))
```

Output

```
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  User      freq
  <chr>    <int>
1 17567123    14
2 17567124     5
3 Jhon         1
```

Comment: Sorry, i update row number 4 is with (.). How to remove the character in front user id?

Comment: i have one char ('\') in my data not two, how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @DioAgusNofrizal, "\\" in R means a single "\" because the first "\" is an escape character. Try `nchar("\\")`.

Comment: I think there is an error in summarise because the function instead calculates the number of freq columns

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you show the error message? @DioAgusNofrizal

Comment: i dont have the error message, but the result in column freq is 20

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I even tried running it in an [online R console](https://rextester.com/DADRL62054) but still got the correct result. You may want to clean up your global environment or restart Rstudio. @DioAgusNofrizal